# Unused import statement - Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Ao tentar fazer o import usando no  `Pycharm`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
```

ele deixa o texto em cinza, e mostra `unused import statemnet`.

tentei usar o:

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
```

mas sem sucesso, por que isso acontece?

Comment: Basta tirar o import desnecessário. A sugestão de usar o módulo só pra sumir com o warning é meio... "estranha", por assim dizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplismente porque você não está usando o modulo que você fez import, use em algum lugar do codigo e o warning deve sumir em breve.

Comment: Já tinha resolvido, exatamente isso..ta ai pra quem precisar